# How to grab a value from vue.js data into a another data parameter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I am using vue.js and vue-qrcode
I store some user data in localStorage and get it correctly.

```
<template>
    <div class="row" style="100%;">
        <div class="center-block" style="width:200px">
            <qrcode :size="size" :val="val"></qrcode>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{content.last}}
</template>
<script>
    import store from '../store'
    var content = [];
    export default {
        data() {
                return {
                    content: store.todoStorage.fetch(),
                    size: 250,
                    fgColor: '#007a33',
                    bgColor: '#ffc72c',
                    val: "BEGIN:VCARD\r\nVERSION:2.1\r\nN:john;doe\r\nFN:asd " + content.last + "\r\nTEL;TYPE=cell:234\r\nEMAIL;PREF;INTERNET:234234\r\nEND:VCARD"
                }
            },
            components: {
                qrcode: VueQr
            },

    }

</script>
```

I tried putting string into the template, where it works, but, the QR is malformed somehow. If I remove the variable and use just text in the data() val model, QR is perfect and it works. But, I need to grab 4 values from the content model above.

Comment: I just tested putting it also in computed value... the this.content.last is coming back undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell without seeing your entire Vue app. This much is for sure, you cannot use `content.last` in you `val` object as it will be undefined. Basically you are assigning it before it exists. A computed object should help there.

something like:

```
computed: {
  val() {
    var content = store.todoStorage.fetch();
    return "BEGIN:VCARD\r\nVERSION:2.1\r\nN:john;doe\r\nFN:asd " + content.last + "\r\nTEL;TYPE=cell:234\r\nEMAIL;PREF;INTERNET:234234\r\nEND:VCARD"
  }
}
```

Again, not sure if this is going to solve without seeing your code, but it may put you in the right path.

Comment: that was it... I also hda an extra comma at the end